# How can we pass result data from CodeIgniter controller to AngularJS controller?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

How can we pass result data from CodeIgniter controller to AngularJS controller? In CodeIgniter controller using jsonSuccess code  here I'm passing data to AngularJS but I would like to pass different 3 variables

How do I need to pass them and how can I get data?

codeigniter controller code:

```
$siteName   =   $CI->config->item('siteName');
 $siteURL   = site_url();


        if($data['status'] == 'success')

        {


            $result =   $this->LowCredit_model->info($data['data']);

            jsonSuccess($result,$siteName ,$siteURL,$result['succ_code'],$siteName,$siteURL);

        }
```

Angular Controller code:

```
$scope.init     =   function() {


        alert('init');

            gdiztunnel.post( 

            'order/LowCredit', {

               id: $configId 
            }

        ).then(

                function success (response) {

                    response    =   response.data;

                    if(response.status  ==  'success') {

                        $scope.lowcreditCtrl.data = response.data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already gave you the solution this is Repeated Question

```
$data['siteName']   =   $CI->config->item('siteName');
$data['siteURL']   = site_url();
 if($data['status'] == 'success') {
   $data['result'] =   $this->LowCredit_model->info($data['data']);
   jsonSuccess($data);
 }
```