# How to pass some variable to return response data in codeigniter model to controller

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm tying last one day this task but till now i'm not getting. Actually i Have codeigniter model data this data i'm passing to controller & this controller to Angularjs CTRL and This CTRL to display HTML page .

In model i have variables in siteurl & siteName and I have DB table data. these all the data i want to return response array. i'm returning but  siteurl & siteName is not return & other datas firstname,lastname,email coming .please help me.

I have put print_r($result) in controller not coming siteurl & siteName is not return & other datas coming:

This is my Model code:

```
  $siteURLs  = site_url();    
  $data['siteurl'] = $siteURLs.'credits';     
  $data['siteName'] = $siteName;

  $iddss = $params['id'];    
  $data = $this->db->select('id, credit, firstName, lastName, email')    
                ->where('id', $iddss)    
                ->where('archived is NULL')    
                ->get('users')    
                ->row_array();

  $response = array('status'=> 'success',
                    'message'=> $this>lang>line('succ_update_1'),
                    'succ_code'=> 'succ_update_1',
                    'data'=> $data);

  hLog($response,6,$params['id']);    
  return $response;
```

This is my Controller code:

```
  function index()        
  {        
     $data = validate_my_params(array('id' => 'required|id'));        
     if($data['status'] == 'success')        
     {        
        $result = $this->LowCredit_model->info($data['data']);
        print_r($result);
        jsonSuccess($result,$result['succ_code']);        
     }
  }
```

Comment: Same Question yesterday answered !! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60632311/how-can-we-pass-result-data-from-codeigniter-controller-to-angularjs-controller

Comment: Hello Boominathan Elango, The siteName & sitURL only coming rest of data not coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Again i provide same question solution You can  **pass the site_url() from controller**  too  **No need to pass from Model**
>
> Your **Model** Code

```
function info(){

    $iddss = $params['id'];
    $result['siteurl'] =   site_url().'credits'; 
    $result['siteName'] = $siteName;
    $result['status']     =  'success';
    $result['message']    =  $this->lang->line('succ_update_1');
    $result['succ_code']  =  'succ_update_1';

    $result['data'] = $this->db->select('id, credit, firstName, lastName, email')
            ->where('id', $iddss)
            ->where('archived is NULL')
            ->get('users')
            ->row_array();         
      hLog($result,6,$params['id']);
    return $result;
    }
```

> Your **Controller** Code

```
function index(){
$data = validate_my_params(array('id' => 'required|id'));
if($data['status'] == 'success'){
    $result     =   $this->LowCredit_model->info($data['data']);       
    jsonSuccess($result,$result['succ_code']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Boominathan Elango, I have tried above your code it is showing like this . the siteName & siteurl is coming outside of object data i want inside object data. i have put (console.log) the result is : data: {id: "7", credit: "0.00", firstName: "Rahul", lastName: "Joshi", email: "rahul@gdiz.com"}
siteName: "EveryDay Lunch"
siteurl: "https://test.rajkumar.com/credits"

Comment: Answer updated  check it @Sumathraj

Comment: Hello Boominathan Elango, where you updated ?

Comment: The siteName & siteurl coming outside object data . that's why not displaying HTML page . How i need to pass inside object data ...

Comment: Scroll up see my answer !! model codes are modifed !

Comment: Hello  Boominathan Elango thanks for your update i will check.

Comment: hello Boominathan Elango , Sorry i'm not getting User table data . i have tried your above model code.

Comment: Hi  Boominathan Elango , Thanks your valuable time gave to me thanks thanks a lot working your above model code...